# Administrative password not accepted

Tags: debian, password, root, veracrypt

I just finished installing Debian 9.8 Cinnamon and set up a root pwd and my user pwd.
Now I want to install veracrypt and it asks me for my administrative password, but the root password doesn't work.
If i enter terminal, type su, then the same root password i tired with veracrypt gives me root access.

What could be the reason, what password is meant?

Comment: Does it ask for the "administrative" password or the "administrator" password?

Comment: It does ask the 'administrative' password

Comment: Everything I've found shows it asking for the "administrator" password.  Did you obtain it from a reliable source?

Comment: Yes, both OS and the program from the original website. So you're saying I should enter the root password?

Comment: You've tried the root password, but have you tried your own?

Answer (score -1):

The answer varies depending on how you are running *su*.

`[Scottie@Computer] sudo [command] 
 Password:`  This is the password for the user *Scottie*

`[Scottie@Computer] su - 
 Password:`  This is the password for the *root/administrator* user

`[Scottie@Computer] sudo -u George [command] 
 Password:`  This is the password for the user *Scottie*

There may be other variants, so if you are doing something other than these 2, post the command so we can try and figure it out for you.

Comment: `[Scottie@Computer] sudo -u George [command]` will ask for Scottie's password. `[Scottie@Computer] su - George` will ask for George's.